# The actual use of custom configurations in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and struggling with a basic problem. I have a set of compile time dependencies declared in my project. My problem statement is, I want to make a subset of dependencies non transitive and the remaining transitive.

I have tried to make a custom configuration which extends from compile and set its transitive property to `false`.

```
Customcompile.extendsFrom(compile)
Customcompile.transitive = false
```

By this, I assume that whatever I declare with
`Customcompile 'xxx:xxx:1.0'` will have `transitive=false` applied and that it will act as compile time dependency.

But this is not able to compile my project with these dependencies

Am I wrong anywhere in this assumption?

Answer (score 36):

You need to change `customCompile.extendsFrom(compile)` to `compile.extendsFrom(customCompile)`.

```
configurations {
    customCompile
    customCompile.transitive = false
    compile.extendsFrom(customCompile)
}
```

This is because the compilation classpath is derived from the dependencies for the `compile` configuration.

By making `compile` configuration extend from `customCompile` configuration, you are now including all dependencies from `customCompile` configuration into `compile` configuration.

Comment: Isn't this undesirable? Why would one want custom dependencies available at all time. Compile configuration should have common dependencies and custom configuration should have custom dependencies which should only be available for custom configuration. Am I right?